# pgAdmin 4 unable to connect to server: timeout expired

Tags: postgresql, remote-access, remote-server, pgadmin-4

I want to connect to a pgAdmin 4 database by a remote server. However, when I want to save the connection properties, I get the following message:

```
unable to connect to server: timeout expired
```

This the content of the "pg_hba.conf":

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     scram-sha-256
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

listen_addresses in "postgresql.conf" is also set to '*'

What should I do to be able to connect to the server remotely?

Comment: Why don't you put the details (in plain text) in your question?

Comment: First of all.. how you are connecting to remote server ?
Do you have created VPN Tunel ?
Do you setup Firewall rules ?

Comment: I have added a rule to inbound rules in "Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security" to allow the connection.

Comment: Did you try to use other tool like https://dbeaver.io/ ? of course as a way to check if it works or not in your case.

Comment: All the settings in `pg_hba.conf` are for local/localhost connections. A remote connection from another machine will be rejected. See example at bottom pf page here [pg_hba](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) for how to allow remote access.

Comment: I thought that `unable to connect to server: timeout expired` is not related to pg_hba.conf, rather to AV software or to firewall, eventually to any other network related issues. I thought that PosgreSQL state it clearly in error message when pg_hba.conf need to be configured (at least using ADO to connect).